# Linking cells in excel with a specific format

Tags: excel-2007, excel-formula

I am trying to link cells in excel on two different work sheets. 
I am using the formula eg: cell1 = cell2 + cell3. The numbers that I have in cell2 and cell3 are in format of 100% (1) and 50% (2). I just want to add numbers 1 and 2 so that my cell1 will have number 3. 
Is it possible to do without changing the cell formats?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the desired result? 1.5? 150?

Comment: My desired result is 3, addition of (1) and (2).

Comment: How does 100% and 50% equal 3? What are the actual values written in those cells? If you could provide a few examples of of some numbers and the desired result when added maybe we'll be able to help but right now it's not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i understood your question but i'll give some elements:

- formula and formats are separated in Excel, thus, you can set a formula in `A1`, say `=A2+A3` but **displays** the **value** the way you wish
- for instance, if `A2` contains `100%` and `A3` contains `50%`, then the result in `A1` is **worth** `1.5`
- you can set the format of `A1` the way you wish (Right-clic > Format cells > Number tab), for instance, *decimal*, the cell will then **display** `1.5` but if you choose *percentage*, the cell will then **display** `150%`

Please elaborate your question if needed.

[EDIT] New answer thanks to your comment:
If i understand well, you want to sum up the values between brackets in your cell (whatever is before, event percentages in your case).
Then, you can try this in cell `A3`:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("(",A1)+1,FIND(")",A1)-FIND("(",A1)-1 )+MID(A2,FIND("(",A2)+1,FIND(")",A2)-FIND("(",A2)-1 )
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I want to add numbers (1) and (2) instead of adding percentages. The cell as you named in your response, A2 and A3 has values in it which are written as 100%(1) and 50%(2)[which means you are writing percentages and then in brackets you are writing the numbers which generated these percentages). I just want to add numbers and not percentages. I just want my A1 cell to have value 3 in it and no percentages.

Comment: the formula `=A2+A3` will give you the **value**. If you want to display the value as a number (decimal), you will have to change the format: see [here](http://www.helpwithpcs.com/courses/excel-formats.html) for more info. Btw, the cell will display `1.5` because `100%` equals to `1`, right ?

Comment: Thanks Again. I appreciate you time and help. 
You are right. But I am not concerned with percentages at all. Whatever percentage will be there, I just want to add number in the brackets. I just mentioned 100% (1) in my example, but this could also be 100% (4) or 33.33% (2). Thats why I just want to add numbers. Which formula should I use?

Comment: @Nupur: i edited my post with a new answer (i hope i better understood what you meant)

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. It didnt work. Its showing the commomn error VALUE!. I am sorry, I just dont know how to explain but I think you understood what I was trying to say.

Comment: There may be a mistake in my formula since i had to translate it from french. Try to understand what i did and debug it yourself, it will be a good exercise :). If you still can't figure it out, come back and we'll give you another hand

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the percentages, just copy your column with the percentages and change the format of that column to value and in sheet 2, do addition on that column instead.

Unfortunately when a cell has a format of percentage and a user enters a number, it is converted into what it means given the context of the format. It's not like what is being displayed is wildly different than what is 'hidden' inside the cell. When you reformat a cell, that data is reformatted as well, so 50% becomes .5 even if you had originally entered 50 in the cell before changing it's format. Format is more than just 'display format' so maybe that's where the confusion is.

If you want to add the cells in the percentage row and not bother with reformatting the formula cell you can cheat and treat it as a string to get rid of that %. You could do =Left(A2+A3, Len(A2+A3)) that will give you the 1.5 answer without having to format te cell.